Why am I getting a "cannot find symbol" error when I Rebuild my class?
I have inserted the code to bring my sql Database into local storage, but I am getting the error. I cannot find any examples of the imports needed to overcome the error with any of the examples I found of the copyDb(path) usage. Any ideas of the class I need that has the copyDb method in it? I have some imports to delete for this class, but I wanted to get this solved so I can start troubleshooting. Thanks in advance.
Edit: Environment - IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5 (Ultimate Edition), Maven Framework, JDK 11.0.19, Building for Android and iOS.
I am working in the simulator. The copyDb shows red, the roll over says create the method, and the error message is "cannot find symbol" on the copyDb(path); line when I rebuild.
import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.components.ScaleImageLabel;
import com.codename1.system.Lifecycle;
import com.codename1.ui.*;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.*;
import com.codename1.io.*;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.*;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.io.File;
import com.codename1.util.StringUtil;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.codename1.db.Cursor;
import com.codename1.db.Database;
import com.codename1.db.Row;
import com.codename1.io.FileSystemStorage;

public class Rondos {
    Form rondos = new Form(new FlowLayout());
    FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    public Rondos() throws IOException {
        String path = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("rndo.db");
        if(path != null && !FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(path)) {
            copyDb(path);
        }
        Database myDataBase = com.codename1.db.Database.openOrCreate("rndo.db");



Can you edit the question to include the actual error you're getting and for which line in the code? Also, are you using Maven? Which IDE? Which OS? Which JDK?

Thanks, Shai. IntelliJ, Maven Framework, JDK 11.0.19, Building for Android and iOS.

Great but what's the full error? Which symbol specifically isn't found? Looking through your imports this import org.w3c.dom.Text; seems out of place, naturally we don't have that class. Hard to tell if there's anything else.

I posted the screenshot of the same error from another class. I have 4 classes I need to import databases into, which all give the same error.

You're invoking a method copyDb on the same class but you didn't define a copyDb method. Notice you can see a full description of the error by moving up the error hierarchy and you can see the actual text of the error there.

Thanks, Shai. I viewed many answers that suggested the copyDb(path); method, and I was looking for a reference for the method so I could incorporate it because I knew you and others had used the method successfully. I just reread the DBDemo.java and saw the method there. I also notice that the Util.copy(i, o): method doesn't use copyDb. Is one way better than the other?

It's just a method name used to indicate you should copy the pre-existing database from "somewhere". It is expected that you would implement that method since we don't know the type of code you would write.
